# arranging text files side by side using python

Tags: python, pandas, linux, numpy, for-loop

I have 3000 text files in a directory and each `.txt` file contain single column data. i want to arrange them side by side to make it a mxn matrix file.

For example: `paste 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt .............3000.txt`  in linux

For this i tried

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | sort -n | xargs -d '\n' paste
```

However it gives error paste: `filename.txt: Too many open files`

please suggest a better solution for the same using python.

Comment: What is `import glob; pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob.glob("*.txt")], axis=1)` giving?

Comment: You could avoid that error easily by using the command `ulimit -n 4096` to set the open files limit to 4096. (Not a python solution, so I didn't try to make it an answer.)

Comment: @cycolo Then chain `.dropna(how="all")` so it drops rows that have all `NaN`s.

Comment: I meant `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob.glob("*.txt")], axis=1).dropna(how="all")`...

Comment: Without a [mcve] that's all I could do, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: It works fine for me. I just used a simplified version of your command, after I increased the open file limit, to paste the files in numeric order. Ulimit won't change the way `sort` sorts.

Comment: Do all of your files have the same number of lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the inputs received, please follow the below steps.

```sh
# Change ulimit to increase the no of open files at a time
$ ulimit -n 4096

# Remove blank lines from all the files
$ sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' *.txt

# Join all files side by side to form a matrix view
$ paste $(ls -v *.txt) > matrix.txt

# Fill the blank values in the matrix view with 0's using awk inplace
$ awk -i inplace 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1' matrix.txt
```

Comment: Many Thanks @BarathVutukuri  for your smart answer....finally it solved my problem...you are really an expert...

Comment: The sed step to remove blank lines can be optional, you can directly use paste command and run awk. But the output will be different in each method. Please check which is the desired output for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* python for this; if you first increase the number of open files a process can have using `ulimit`, it becomes easy to get columns in the right order in `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh93` shells, using `paste` and [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to generate the filenames in the desired order instead of having to sort the results of filename expansion:

```sh
% ulimit -n 4096
% paste {1..3000}.txt > matrix.txt
```

(I tested this in all three shells I mentioned on a Linux box, and it works with all of them with no errors about the command line being too long or anything else.)

You could also arrange to have the original files use a different naming scheme that sorts naturally, like `0001.txt`, `0002.txt`, ..., `3000.txt` and then just `paste [0-9]*.txt > matrix.txt`.

Comment: @cycolo `-u` controls the number of processes a user can have running at once, and is quite irrelevant here.

Comment: Just in case, `[0-9]*` is any file whose name starts with a digit, not any file whose name is only digits.

Comment: It's because the files are of different lengths.

Comment: @cyco lo please check if the no of lines are equal in all the files. `wc -l *.txt`

Comment: @Shawn without changing the original filenames, natural sorting can be achieved by using `ls -v`.  `paste $(ls -v *.txt) > output.txt`