# arrange the text files side by side to make a matrix file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, join

I have 3000 text files in a directory and each .txt file contain single column data. i want to arrange them side by side to make it a mxn matrix file.

For this i tried

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | sort -n | xargs -d '\n' paste
```

However it gives error paste: filename.txt: Too many open files

please suggest a better solution for the same using python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arranging text files side by side using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233631/arranging-text-files-side-by-side-using-python)

Comment: No it doesnot...

Comment: Okay, the above suggested answer didn't provide an answer to your specific question, can you explain what specifically was wrong with the suggested approach?  Also, can you give us a hint as to how many data points exist in each of the 3000 files.  Please provide a sample of the type of data in the file, and an idea of what you want the output file to look like.

Comment: Don't open the same question more than one time, they will be closed as duplicates. Instead, update the existing question if it's not answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

For relatively short files that include a unique column Name in the first line of the text file, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path 

def listFiles(ddir):
    #return a list of txt files in the file directory specified by ddir
    p = Path(ddir)
    return list(p.glob('*.txt'))  

def readfile_toDataframe(file):
    #create a dataframe from the contents of file
    return pd.read_csv(file)

def joinDfs(list_of_files):
    # Read a list of files and join their contents on the index
    dfo = readfile_toDataframe(list_of_files[0])
    for f in list_of_files[1:]:
        dfo = dfo.join(readfile_toDataframe(f))
    return dfo
```

by running:

```
joinDFs(listFiles(ddir))
```

where ddir is a string variable pointing to the file directory, you will read the files and create a DataFrame of their contents with each file being a column.