# making large matrix using text files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 3000 text files in a directory and each .txt file contain single column data. i want to arrange them side by side to make it a `mxn` matrix file and want to save mxn large file.I have tried varies solution using experts answer but none is successful.Hence i need full support from stackoverflow community.

For this i tried

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
cc=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob.glob("*.txt")], axis=1)
```

However it gives nan values at the end of file

please suggest a better solution for the same using python.

Comment: i already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233631/arranging-text-files-side-by-side-using-python

Comment: What does the "typical" txt file look like? Can you share a sample?

Comment: Could you repost the link to the text files?

Answer (score 0):

Nan values are expected if different files have a different number of rows, because Pandas has nothing to fill in for certain row, column combinations.  You can fill the nan with '' (or any other value you want), or drop any rows or columns that are entirely empty.

```
row1list = ['stack']
row2list = ['overflow']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list])

row1list = ['stack']
row2list = ['overflow']
row3list = ['and more']
df2 = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list])

cc = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

print(cc)
#           0         0
# 0     stack     stack
# 1  overflow  overflow
# 2       NaN  and more

cc = cc.fillna('')
print(cc)
#           0         0
# 0     stack     stack
# 1  overflow  overflow
# 2            and more

# delete any empty columns & any empty rows
# Drop the rows where all elements are missing.   # how='all' to require that every instance (not just 1) is null
cc = cc.dropna(how='all', axis='columns')
cc = cc.dropna(how='all', axis='rows')
```